# Composed Task Properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

we have a scenario where we want to pass the same properties to all tasks in a composed.

`app.composed-task-runner.composed-task-arguments='c=d,a=b'` doesn’t work.

version used 2.0.0.M2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `--composed-task-arguments=c=d,a=b` without any spaces make it work

Comment: there's some contradictions in the documentation https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/4847